# There must follow two lines text after a section title

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

As shown in the image, the section title will be on the first page if two lines of text after it.

The section title will move to the next page if a line is added.

How to keep one title on the first page when adding one line of text?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{title}
\lipsum[1-3]
%If have this line, it will break the page here.
\section{title}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is expected bahaviour, as TeX is trying to avoid single lines of text at the end of a page, so called orphans (as well as single lines of text at the top of the page, so called widows).

Comment: ... but what is your question?

Comment: My question is how to allow "orphans and widows". Now I know the way to implement this feature.  \usepackage[defaultlines=1,all]{nowidow} @JasperHabicht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestion of @JasperHabicht, now I know the phenomenon is called orphans or widows.

We can use the `nowidow` package to allow it.

```
\usepackage[defaultlines=1,all]{nowidow}
```

[image]